# Bootstrap Tabs: Prevent auto-scrolling when switching between tabs of different lengths

Tags: html, tabs, bootstrap-5

I have several Bootstrap tabs with contents of varying lengths:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam rem accusantium dolor voluptates delectus nesciunt id laudantium et pariatur ipsum nihil inventore sit culpa voluptatem vero, necessitatibus, magnam quasi! Ab perferendis, earum molestiae placeat nihil inventore consequuntur? Saepe architecto adipisci earum ullam consequuntur eius laboriosam officiis esse officia a veritatis perferendis beatae ipsa aperiam ut laborum commodi dolorem quo, harum quae. Dolor voluptate sint unde totam saepe consequatur repellat, praesentium debitis soluta illo veritatis? Dolorum veritatis non totam, alias soluta voluptate, porro corrupti accusamus enim autem placeat quisquam eos, quos mollitia nihil voluptas magni. Impedit autem esse a omnis corrupti?
</div>
</div>
```

Whenever switching between tabs of different lengths (mostly going from longer to shorter) the screen auto-scrolls to fit the content. It's a nitpick, I know, but is there anyway to prevent this behavior? Basically I want the tab titles to always be in the same place.

Or is this pretty much impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The below seemed to fix my issue, maybe it will fix yours.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-link").click(function(e) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if anyone looks for solution, this worked for me.

```js
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

  for (const navLink of navLinks) {
    navLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.scrollTo(window.pageXOffset, window.pageYOffset);
    });
  }
```